# Text on Button not visible on Button Android layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

So I'm using text on button like this and I'm using picasso to display the images but I think the text on button is behind the picasso images how to make text appear up front to the images

Full XML Layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/aboutview"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/aboutus1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/contacts"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>



        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
             >

             <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/acc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

              <ImageButton
                  android:id="@+id/sw6products"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1.4"
                  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                  android:background="@color/White"
                  android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/plans"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

             <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/shops"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/vids"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />




        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Picasso Code

```
imgButtons9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.acc);
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.acc).into(imgButtons9);
```

Comment: post full layout file and if possible post screenshot.

Comment: Don't you need to declare your Button as an ImageButton in XML?

Comment: Yes Is there a way I can put text in Imagebutton btw I'm on table layout

Comment: You can use simple Button, and set its drawable with `setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: But the problem is I have picasso on my mainactivity java that uses image buttons. Tried that one but it gives me FC as soon as I open my app because of missing imagebuttons on layout

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for button (not imagebutton)

```
Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
                button.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
            }
            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {}
            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) { }
        };
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://developer.android.com/images/material.png").into(target);
```